# Button get data from table row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to get the data from the table row using jQuery. I'm trying to get "b17dcat126" but it returned none instead.

```js
function updatedata() {
  var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
  var id = tr.find('.id').text();
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<tbody id="list">
  <tr class='row'>
    <td class='id'>b17dcat126</td>
    <td class='name'>Nguyễn Nhật Minh</td>
    <td class='phone'>010313234</td>
    <td class='sex'>Nam</td>
    <td>
      <button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deletefunc(15)' data-id='15'>Xoá</button>
      <button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' onclick='updatedata()' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.*** You are using jQuery, so you can simplify your code too much. remove `onclick` from button and directly do:

```
$('.btn-warning').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();  
  alert(id);
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$('.btn-warning').click(function() {
  var ids = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();
  alert(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody id="list">
  <tr class='row'>
    <td class='id'>b17dcat126</td>
    <td class='name'>Nguyễn Nhật Minh</td>
    <td class='phone'>010313234</td>
    <td class='sex'>Nam</td>
    <td>
      <button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

***2.*** Your code will work as well, if you pass button object to the function:

Working snippet:

```js
function updatedata(element) {
    var id = $(element).closest("tr").find('.id').text();
    alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody id="list">
            <tr class='row'>
                <td class='id'>b17dcat126</td>
                <td class='name'>Nguyễn Nhật Minh</td>
                <td class='phone'>010313234</td>
                <td class='sex'>Nam</td>
                <td>
                    <button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' onclick='updatedata(this)' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword inside the function is referring to the global object. 
You could solve this by two way.

1. Create the event listener using `Jquery`.
2. Or pass the `this` keyword as the function argument.

**First approach:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".updateBtn").click(function() {
        var tr = $(this).parents("tr");
        var id = tr.find('.id').text();
        alert(id);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody id="list">
            <tr class='row'>
                <td class='id'>b17dcat126</td>
                <td class='name'>Nguyễn Nhật Minh</td>
                <td class='phone'>010313234</td>
                <td class='sex'>Nam</td>
                <td>
                    <button class='btn btn-warning updateBtn' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Second approach:**

```js
function updatedata(current) {
    var tr = $(current).parents("tr");
    var id = tr.find('.id').text();
    alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody id="list">
            <tr class='row'>
                <td class='id'>b17dcat126</td>
                <td class='name'>Nguyễn Nhật Minh</td>
                <td class='phone'>010313234</td>
                <td class='sex'>Nam</td>
                <td>
                  
                    <button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' onclick='updatedata(this)' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass event object as function argument to solve this problem.

In HTML,

```
<button class='btn btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' onclick='updatedata(event)' data-target='#update'>Sửa</button>

function updatedata(e) {     
  alert($(e.target).parents('tr').find('td.id').text());
}
```